# Homepage not loading after Wordpress Migration, all other pages load

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, migration

After migrating my Wordpress website, I have been able to get Wordpress to work well. The backend works and all front-end pages load EXCEPT for the homepage. I have tried following all resources online to get it to work, but nothing seems to be helping. At the moment, I have no domain name, accessing the site has been directly through the IP Address. When I type in the new IP Address expecting it to load, it instead redirects to the old IP address.

All other pages work fine though.

This is hosted on Google Cloud Compute Engine.

I have tried following this: [Homepage not loading, all other pages loading in WordPress migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373510/homepage-not-loading-all-other-pages-loading-in-wordpress-migration)

I have also tried running this in phpmyadmin:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value,'http://oldaddress','http://newaddress');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'http://oldaddress','http://newaddress');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid,'http://oldaddress','http://newaddress');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value,'http://oldaddress','http://newaddress');
```

I have also tried following this page: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/
particularly this section: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#edit-wp-config-php

And this section: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#edit-functions-php

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was with my browser caching the website. I cleared the cache on my browser and it all starting working as expected.